# USB 3.0 not functioning fully

Tags: linux, usb

After installing GNU/Linux today onto my Lenovo Y570 laptop, I ran into an issue quickly - the USB 3.0 support. 2/3 of my USB ports are 3.0 so I kind of need them.

The ports are powered at the very least - my phone is charging from one, however, plugging in external drives, USB drives, or even a mouse gives no response. The drives spin up, etc, but they do nothing more than that. So there is power, but no information flowing to them.

What am I missing here? What can I try to enable to make things work?

Comment: Run `dmesg | tail` after you plugin and [edit] & add the log contents

Comment: @Sathya plugged it in to get the output...works perfectly. Odd.